# How can I get my first background-image to be overridden by the mask-image?

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a *really simple example* together that demonstrates how you can use CSS `mask-image` values to override a `background-image` (overriding something else would work too though). I don't quite have enough CSS experience to place all of my properties in the right place. My understanding so far is that this is very possible!

The following code is what I currently have:

```css
.one {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  mask-image: linear-gradient(black, black);
  mask-type: alpha;
  mask-mode: alpha;
}

#imgone {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(blue, blue);
  mask-image: linear-gradient(black, black);
  mask-type: alpha;
  mask-mode: alpha;
}

#imgtwo {
  height: 50%;
  width 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(yellow, yellow);
  mask-image: linear-gradient(black, black);
  mask-type: alpha;
  mask-mode: alpha;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="one">
    <div id="imgone"></div>
    <p>Content</p>
    <div id="imgtwo"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Since `imgone` has an opacity of zero I was expecting one of the `mask-image` values to take over in its place. Right now (in Firefox ESR) all I see is white where `imgone` should be.

Am I close to using a `mask-image` somehow? Or perhaps there are multiple things that need correcting? What's the easiest way to get `imgone` to display a black mask image?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you mean by ‘overridden’ here? Also AFAIK mask-type applies to svgs.

Comment: Hm.. I just want a black box on top instead of a white (empty), blue, or yellow one. I thought masks were supposed to kick in and replace anything that was transparent (opacity 0).

Comment: your understand of mask is not correct. Opacity:0 means hide the element and everything related to that element so what is happening inside (mask, background, etc) is not visible to us. opacity and mask aren't related, they are independant

Comment: I thought I'd read that they were related somewhere.. but maybe not. I guess I'm not really sure what mask layers are for :(

Answer (score 1):

You are confused with the way `mask-image` works.

`mask-image` accepts an image with an alpha mask (usually an svg, but png files should also works) and what it practically does is it sets a mask for the div in the way that alpha map is set.

A great example is the one from [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mask-image/), where they trim the background of a landscape to look like a "sun":

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #8f7a66;
}

.el {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1rem;

  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1528287942171-fbe365d1d9ac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1200&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ);
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  mask-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/sun.svg);
  mask-size: 100vmin;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="el"></div>
```

If you want to use `mask-image` to make something disappear, although unorthodox, you could try and use a totally transparent image as an `image-mask`

Comment: This is helpful. However, I'm still not creating my own example very well. I tried downloading the same files from the example with `wget` but when I add the `mask-image` everything just goes white. I can modify the example if I leave the original URLs. It seems like file types are pretty important for mask layer images. Can you achieve a similar effect with CSS `gradient` types? Or do you absolutely need the right SVG/PNG files?

Comment: `Mask-image` needs an image with an alpha mask. Would you mind explaining what you want to achieve a bit more thoroughly?